# How to add TaskListeer to user task using UserTask class?

Tags: activiti, bpmn

Is there any example doc for Add TaskListener to UserTask..? (Java Base, Using BpmnModel Class)

This is my code and it has run time errors

```
UserTask userTask = new UserTask(); 
ActivitiListener activitiListener = new ActivitiListener();  
activitiListener.setEvent( TaskListener.EVENTNAME_COMPLETE ); 
activitiListener.setImplementation( 
  ImplementationType.IMPLEMENTATION_TYPE_CLASS ); 
activitiListener.setImplementation( "<my_package>.TestTaskListener" );  
userTask.getTaskListeners().add( activitiListener );
```

And Error

```
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Errors while parsing:
[Validation set: 'activiti-executable-process' | Problem: 'activiti- 
usertask-listener-implementation-missing'] : Element 'class' or 'expression' 
is mandatory on executionListener - [Extra info : processDefinitionId = my- 
process | processDefinitionName = my dynamic process | | id = task1 | | 
activityName = First task | ] ( line: 6, column: 74)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you are setting the implementation but the validation at schema level is being done on the "element 'class' or 'expression' 
is mandatory on executionListener". 
So how does your XML look like? are you setting those properties?

Comment: Yes i'm setting up all the properties and generated xml  file using the java code. but i need to add task listener to the user tasks. here is my generated xml usertask.

Comment: <userTask id="task6" name="Office Re-Evaluation of Application" activiti:assignee="user_6" activiti:formKey="form_task6">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="decisionPath" name="decisionList" type="enum" required="true">
          <activiti:value id="1" name="SUCCESS"></activiti:value>
          <activiti:value id="2" name="RETURN TO EVALUATOR"></activiti:value>
        </activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: Using 6.0 version of activiti

Answer (score 0):

1.create a custom task listener

```
@Component(value = "myEventListener")
public class MyEventListener implements TaskListener {
    @Override
    public void notify(DelegateTask delegateTask) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

2.create your user task by java code

```
UserTask userTask = new UserTask();
userTask.setName("");
userTask.setId("");

List<FlowableListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();
FlowableListener listener = new FlowableListener();
listener.setEvent("complete");
listener.setImplementation("${myEventListener}");
listener.setImplementationType("delegateExpression");

listeners.add(listener);
userTask.setTaskListeners(listeners);
```

3.you can use BpmnXMLConverter and convert the BpmnModel to xml string

```
new BpmnAutoLayout(model).execute();
BpmnXMLConverter converter = new BpmnXMLConverter();
byte[] bytes = converter.convertToXML(model);
System.out.println(new String(bytes));
```

the xml might be

```
    <userTask id="taskId" name="taskName">
      <extensionElements>
        <flowable:taskListener event="complete" delegateExpression="${myEventListener}"></flowable:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
```

4.you can also change your code

```
listener.setEvent("complete");
listener.setImplementation("com.xxx.MyEventListener");
listener.setImplementationType("class");
```

the xml might be

```
    <userTask id="taskId" name="taskName">
      <extensionElements>
        <flowable:taskListener event="complete" class="com.xxx.MyEventListener"></flowable:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
```